# New value in HTML.DropDownListFor(...) not setting in Controller [Post] method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

Hopefully someone can see how to go about this, because I've tried everything I can think of. When the **Create()** View in my MVC5 application loads I first populate several `[SelectList(...)]`'s in my Controller (ex.):

```
ViewBag.Model_Id = new SelectList(db.DBT_MODELS.OrderBy(x => x.MODEL_DESCRIPTION), "MODEL_ID", "MODEL_DESCRIPTION");
```

I then on my **Create()** View use this `[SelectList(...)]` to Populate an `Html.DropDownListFor(...)`:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="control-label col-md-2">Model:</span>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MODEL_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Model_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown", @id = "selectModel" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MODEL_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button id="createNewModel" type="button" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">CREATE NEW</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="createModelFormContainer" style="display:none">
                <form action="/createNewModel">
                    <input type="text" id="textNewModel" name="model_description" placeholder="New Model" />
                    <input type="button" id="submitNewModel" value="Submit" />
                    <input type="button" id="cancelNewModel" value="Cancel" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Simple enough, and this all works as expected. The problem lies in a bit of extended functionality I've tried to incorporate. My main class has several of these properties which are basically Foreign Key's in my DB. When a User goes in to `Create/Edit()` an entity in my main Model, I wanted to allow them to be able to add new entities to these foreign tables without needing to navigate away from the current `View`.

As such, I added (for each foreign property, using (Model) as an example) the code shown above and again directly below with a button to Show/Hide a small form for users to insert a new value and have it added to the DropDownList:

```
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button id="createNewModel" type="button" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">CREATE NEW</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="createModelFormContainer" style="display:none">
                <form action="/createNewModel">
                    <input type="text" id="textNewModel" name="model_description" placeholder="New Model" />
                    <input type="button" id="submitNewModel" value="Submit" />
                    <input type="button" id="cancelNewModel" value="Cancel" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My `submitNewModel()` click event below gets the user's inputted new value and then uses a JSON call to a Controller Method to add it in the Database Table. This new value (and new ID for it) are then returned, the form for the DropDownList is reset, and I set the DropDownList's current value as the newly added one:

```
        $('#createNewModel').click(function () {
            $('#createModelFormContainer').show();
        })

        $('#cancelNewModel').click(function () {
            $('#createModelFormContainer').hide();
        })

        $('#submitNewModel').click(function () {
            var form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = { description: document.getElementById('textNewModel').value };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("createNewModel", "INV_ASSETS")',
                data: data,
                success: function (resp) {
                    if (resp.ModelExists)
                    {
                        alert("Model [" + resp.Text + "] already exists. Please select from the DropDown.");
                    } else {
                        $('#selectModel').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.MODEL_ID).text(resp.Text));
                        form[0].reset();
                        $('#createModelFormContainer').hide();
                        var count = $('#selectModel option').size();
                        $('#selectModel').prop('selectedIndex', count - 1);
                        $('#selectModel').val(resp.MODEL_ID);
                        //document.getElementById('selectModel').value = resp.MODEL_ID; - Shows dropdown as blank [      ] once executed.
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("ERROR - Something went wrong adding new Model [" + resp.Text + "]!");
                    $('#createModelFormContainer').hide();
                }
            });
            //reloadForNewEntity();
        });
```

The `createNewModel()` method that is called in my Controller:

```
    public JsonResult createNewModel(string description)
    {
        DBT_MODELS model = new DBT_MODELS()
        {
            // ID auto-set during save.
            MODEL_DESCRIPTION = description.Trim(),
            CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now,
            CREATED_BY = System.Environment.UserName
        };

        var duplicateModel = db.DBT_MODELS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MODEL_DESCRIPTION.ToUpper() == model.MODEL_DESCRIPTION.ToUpper());

        try
        {
            if (duplicateModel == null)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.DBT_MODELS.Add(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    // Ensure the [model.ID] is properly set after having been saved to and auto-generated in the database.
                    model.MODEL_ID = db.DBT_MODELS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MODEL_DESCRIPTION.ToUpper() == model.MODEL_DESCRIPTION.ToUpper()).MODEL_ID;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                model = duplicateModel;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }

        return Json(new { ID = model.MODEL_ID, Text = model.MODEL_DESCRIPTION, ModelExists = (duplicateModel != null) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Visually speaking, everything works as intended up to this point. The problem is when I go to Save the main entity I am Creating/Editing.

Any value that was already in the Foreign Tables, and thus in the DropDownList when the View loads, saves just fine; but if I add a new Foreign Table value for these main entity properties (though visually added and the currently selected values for the individual DropDownLists) the `[POST]` method then executes with each foreign id value set as `0` (ex. MainClass.Model_ID = "0" vs expected MainClass.Model_ID = "625", MainClass.Type_ID = "0" vs expected MainClass.Type_ID = "17", MainClass.Location_ID = "0" vs expected MainClass.Location_ID = "82", etc.)

Basically if the value selected in the `Html.DropDownListFor()` is one of my newly added values, the `POST` controller method always renders the `MainClass.*_ID` value which the selected `Html.DropDownListFor()` value corresponds to as "0".

Can anyone point me to how to get this working? I have tried:

- Changing how my JavaScript sets the value in the DropDownList after the the JSON call to my Controller Actions returns (ex): `//document.getElementById('selectModel').value = resp.MODEL_ID; - Shows dropdown as blank [      ] once executed.` vs `$('#selectModel').val(resp.MODEL_ID);` which visually renders the expected new value in the DropDownList.
- On return from the Controller method, setting a new ViewBag variable and then hoping to reference the saved value in the POST method (did not work, the JavaScript rendered my `@Viewbag.PostModelID = resp.ModelID` as "= resp.ModelID" and threw many expected errors).

---

**EDIT**:

[Redacted for N/A]

**EDIT2**: Good to go. Thanks everyone for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json data you are returning from your action method is in this format.

```
{
    "ID": 24,
    "Text": "IOS",
    "ModelExists": false
}
```

But in your code, you are trying to access `MODEL_ID` property which does not exist in the resp object.

```
$('#selectModel').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.MODEL_ID).text(resp.Text));
```

Change your code to use `ID` property value

```
$('#selectModel').append($('<option></option>').val(resp.ID).text(resp.Text));
$('#selectModel').val(resp.ID);
```

Comment: Hello Shyju, your suggestion was spot on! (really annoyed I overlooked such an easy slip). I proceeded to rename that return property for all dropdown's as `New***ID` to keep it coherent. All is working now except for the Owner dropdown list. Would you mind taking a look at my Edit above?

Comment: Scratch that, I decided to just go ahead and forge through with making the Owner DB setup the same as the rest. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller where you create the new model.. your json object that you're returning is `ID, Text, ModelExists`, but in your javascript you're setting the val property of the new `<option>` to `MODEL_ID`.. these 2 need to match..

So change your javascript to be

```
.val(resp.ID)
```

or change the return value in your controller action to

```
return Json(new { MODEL_ID = model.MODEL_ID, Text = model.MODEL_DESCRIPTION
```

You're also referencing `MODEL_ID` here

```
$('#selectModel').val(resp.MODEL_ID);
```

so make sure if you don't change your controller action, you update this also